# Accessing the image in NetBeans for JSP

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans

I am writing a code to create roll over effect using the **NetBeansIDE**.

I am unable to access the image with following code during the rollover in browser:

```
 <script language="javascript">
    function MouseRollover(MyImage) {
     MyImage.src = "images\button2.jpg";
}
    function MouseOut(MyImage) {
            MyImage.src = "images\button1.jpg";
}
```

However the browser successfully loads another image ***strip.png*** present in same folder:

```
<img src="images\strip.png" alt="Image can't be displayed" width="1319" height="192">
```

Also, whenever page loads initially it successfully displays the image. But it doesn't display any image whenever ***onMouseOver*** and ***onMouseOut*** events occur.

Image code:

```
 <img alt="Image can't be displayed"  src="images\button1.jpg" 
                     name="button" width="217" height="115" 
                     border="0" id="button" 
                     onMouseOver="MouseRollover(this)" 
                     onMouseOut="MouseOut(this)"
                     title="Register yourself">
```

Below is my project's directory structure:

[image]

How is this error caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `/` as folder/filename separator symbol.

Instead of `images\button1.jpg` use `images/button1.jpg`

Error caused by incorrect interpretation of symbols sequence. `\` symbol means escape sequence start. and `\b` means backspace escape sequence.

Use `/` symbol instead of `\` and it should help to fix your issue.